# How can Swift code on macOS continuously read from and/or write to a named pipe

Tags: swift, macos, pipe, named-pipes

I need to be able to constantly read from and write to the pipe from my Swift code.

I am aware of the mkfifo terminal command on macOS, but none of the documentation I have seen addresses this specific use case, and I am unable to find any examples.

Comment: Have you looked at [`NSPipe`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspipe)?

Comment: @Alexander: NSPipe (and Pipe, it's Swift equivalent) are anonymous pipes. I need to use named pipes.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. In that case, you're looking for [`NSFileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilehandle)